# How to remove all multiple quotes in text

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a string and its contains multiple double quotes, how can I remove all multiple quotes?

**Example:**

```
 ""Text1"", ""Text2", """Text3""
```

**Output should be:**

```
 "Text1","Text2","Text3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### how can I remove all multiple quotes

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `""+`
- Set "Replace with" to `"`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
""Text1"", ""Text2", """Text3""
```

**After**:

```
"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This example may distort the results like "Text1 = ""Text2""".

You can use this option.
Replace """" with @2, then "" with @1, then " with an empty string. Then replace @2 with "" and @1 with "

In steps it will be:

- "Text1 = ""Text2"""
- Text 1 = @1Text2@1"
- Text1 = @1Text2@1
- Text1 = "Text2"

Comment: Where your examples come from? They don't exist in OP's question.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].